Is it possible to extrude a bone only from either head or tail but not both?
So, when I try to extrude a bone, it does so from both the head and tail of the bone. Is it possible to extrude only from one of them?

Hello, it should extrude from the tail, could you please show a screenshot or an animated gif?

Here: https://i.imgur.com/tzR93yV.gif

oh ok so why don't you select from the tail or the head only?

It looks as if you've selected the whole of the bone rather than just the tail in which case you'll get two bones extruded, one from head and one from tail.

because clicking on the head or tail doesn't do anything

Extrusion takes selection into account.
If a tail is selected, a connected, child bone will be extruded from the tail. If a head is selected, a sibling bone will be extruded from the head. By sibling, I mean the new bone will be at the same level in the hierarchy as the bone from whose head it was extruded. It will also share the same connected state.

If a bone is selected, a connected, child bone will be extruded from its tail.

If the selection includes multiple elements, a bone will be extruded from each element following what was mentioned above. Note that selecting a connected bone implicitly selects the head of its parent.

In summary, yes, it's possible to extrude from the head or tail individually by limiting the selection to one of them.
Note that selecting the head or tail works in all armature display types; it is just not properly shown in the Stick display type (which is most likely a bug).

Blender version 4.2.0

@MrA Okay, your edit seems to make it unnecessary complicated talking about siblings, hierarchy levels etc... would you mind editing your own answer?
